# How to grunt concat in a wrapping function

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have three files containing js classes:

```js
A.js
B.js
C.js
```

I'm trying to concatenate them to get something like:

```js
var Module = (function (scope) {
// content of concatenation (ABC.js)
})(scope);
```

For now I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat to concatenate, I saw https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-wrap, it seems to be abandonned but look like what I want.

Someone has an idea to achieve it without using grunt-concat?

PS: I want to keep a *.map file for debug purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the banner/footer of https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat?

Or this kind of concatenation with 2 files for intro and outro? [I'm trying out Grunt and need a simple way to concatenate my modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907678/im-trying-out-grunt-and-need-a-simple-way-to-concatenate-my-modules)

Comment: intro and outro. Thanks for that, I think it's the cleanest way to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to have a look at [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim). It's an excellent way of scoping your dependencies without polluting the global namespace. It's works well with grunt and gulp and supports sourcemaps too.