# How to access environment variables in Grunt file

Tags: javascript, heroku, gruntjs, webstorm

I have an angular application which runs in 3 different environment- **Development**, **Staging** and **Production**. 
Heroku builds the application based on my build script. I have a Gruntfile which as **release** task which uglifies the code.

Heroku runs this command **Grunt release** for both staging and production environment.

But I need logs to be enabled in staging and disabled in production environment.

For doing this, I tried accessing process.env.NODE_ENV in my grunt file. But it says process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined.

I am using webstorm to start the server in which I have defined process.env.NODE_ENV to production. But I am unable to access this in Grunt file.

Kindly let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add some code at the bebening of your app?
Like

```
var debug = true;
```

You can achieve this with banner/footer or putting a intro file when concatenating your files like here [I'm trying out Grunt and need a simple way to concatenate my modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907678/im-trying-out-grunt-and-need-a-simple-way-to-concatenate-my-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku [has its own way of handling config/environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior), and also deliberately leaves `NODE_ENV` unset.

Run `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production` in the working directory of your project to have that available in your build when you deploy. Any environment variable you set should be available on `process.env`.