# Using grunt js, how can I dynamically add the <title> to static html files?

Tags: html, json, build-process, concatenation, gruntjs

More specifically, I want to add the titles by referencing an external JSON file, let's call it titles.json.

One of the things I use grunt for is to build static HTML files for design and debugging. This would be really helpful during development, not just for titles but potentially other data as well, such as setting the active nav link.

I'm currently concatenating HTML files using the process described by the accepted answer here:
[Using grunt concat, how would I automate the concatenation of the same file to many other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722855/using-grunt-concat-how-would-i-automate-the-concatenation-of-the-same-file-to-m?lq=1)

EDIT: **I now use [assemble](http://github.com/assemble/assemble) for this**, it was created to make working with templates and external data very easy.

Comment: How do you actually want to link titles to html pages? Do you reference html files in titles.json? And what about links? It would be easier to help you out with this if you provided a sample json definition you would like to be able to use

Comment: Also, if you have such long-going plans, you might want to consider static website generators like [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/usage). They should already have all the common functionality you describe.

Comment: Good questions. And thanks again for helping with the last question - it has made a big impact on my time. I'm going to keep this simple in my projects, so there might be two json files: titles.json, and links.json. It seems to make sense to use the names of the html files to match the data. Since I work on a lot of small projects where the file names are almost always the same: index.html, about.html, contact.html etc. So I'm thinking that when index.html compiles, the script would set the active class on the nav for that file. I'll link a jsfiddle in a minute to show exactly what I mean

Comment: actually, I don't think I need an external json file to do this. Seems like it would make more sense to do this right inside the gruntfile. Here is the jsfiddle for the nav: http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/hprTQ/   To your point about Jekyll, I appreciate where you're coming from. I'm very familiar with Jekyll, but I'm moving towards a different goal with this. I'm happy to provide more detail on the "big picture", but it's probably better explained in a different format so the gods of SO don't rain down upon me...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my take on this. Uses grunt's standard template mechanism, page metadata is defined in an object, outside of actual page files, as you suggested (I can't say I like this).

**gruntfile** (including the `wrap` task from [Using grunt concat, how would I automate the concatenation of the same file to many other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722855/using-grunt-concat-how-would-i-automate-the-concatenation-of-the-same-file-to-m?lq=1)):

```
/*global module:false*/    
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    meta: {
      version: '0.1.0',
      banner: '/*! PROJECT_NAME - v<%= meta.version %> - ' +
        '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
        '* http://PROJECT_WEBSITE/\n' +
        '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ' +
        'YOUR_NAME; Licensed MIT */'
    },

    // Paths
    project: {
      partials: 'assets/partials',  // don't put trailing slash
      pages:    'assets/pages',     // don't put trailing slash
      less:     'assets/less',
      css:      'assets/css',
      img:      'assets/img',
      js:       'assets/js'
    },

    // Used for page title and nav generation.
    // It's an array to ensure correct order for nav
    pages: [{   
        file: 'index.html',
        title: 'My homepage'
        /* This format can be extended to something like:
         * {
         *      title: 'My homepage',
         *      header: 'Welcome to my site',
         *      navtitle: 'Home'
         * }
         * Although I think it's best to keep page metadata as close to content as possible,
         * i.e. right inside pages files (think YAML headers in Jekyll pages)  
         */
    }, {
        file: 'about.html',
        title: 'About me'
    }, {
        file: 'contact.html',
        title: 'Contact'
    }],

    // wraps files with header and footer
    wrap: {
        html: {
            header: '<%= project.partials %>/head.tmpl',
            footer: '<%= project.partials %>/footer.tmpl',
            src: [
                '<%= project.pages %>/index.html',
                '<%= project.pages %>/about.html',
                '<%= project.pages %>/contact.html'
            ],
            dest: '.'   // destination *directory*, probably better than specifying same file names twice
        }
    },

    // processes templates in page files
    buildPages: {
        pages: '<config:pages>',    // page files metadata
        dir: '.'                    // page files location dir
    }

  });


  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'wrap buildPages');

  grunt.registerMultiTask('wrap', 'Wraps source files with specified header and footer', function() {
        var data = this.data,
            path = require('path'),
            dest = grunt.template.process(data.dest),
            files = grunt.file.expandFiles(this.file.src),
            header = grunt.file.read(grunt.template.process(data.header)),
            footer = grunt.file.read(grunt.template.process(data.footer)),
            sep = grunt.utils.linefeed; 

        files.forEach(function(f) {
            var p = dest + '/' + path.basename(f),
                contents = grunt.file.read(f);

            grunt.file.write(p, header + sep + contents + sep + footer);
            grunt.log.writeln('File "' + p + '" created.');
        });
  });

  grunt.registerTask('buildPages', 'Processes templates in page files', function() {
  // NOTE: current implementation replaces files
    var data = grunt.config('buildPages'),
        pages = data.pages,
        dir = data.dir,
        contents,
        curPath;

    pages.forEach(function(page) {
        curPath = dir + '/' + page.file;
        contents = grunt.file.read(curPath);

        // feed the entire pages array and current entry to the template
        grunt.file.write(curPath, grunt.template.process(contents, {
            pages: pages,
            curPage: page
        }));
        grunt.log.writeln('Page at "' + curPath + '" built.');
    });
  });
};
```

**head.tmpl:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= curPage.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- NAV -->
        <ul class="nav">
            <%
                pages.forEach(function(p) {
                    print(
                        '<li class="' + ((curPage === p) ? 'active' : '') + '">' +
                            ((curPage === p) ? p.title : ('<a href="' + p.file + '">' + p.title + '</a>')) + 
                        '</li>\n'
                    );
                });
            %>
        </ul>
        <!-- /NAV -->

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="main">
```

**footer.tmpl:**

```
        </div>
        <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! I really appreciate how much help you've been